# How to create VBA loop for Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I want to loop some VBA code on Form_Load that will update one field in my Form based on 2 other fields.  Currently it will only update the first record or when I click on a record.

Currently it looks like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    If Style = "W" And Size = "120" Then ContainerType = 9
    If Style = "W" And Size = "240" Then ContainerType = 2
    If Style = "W" And Size = "360" Then ContainerType = 34
    If Style = "R" And Size = "120" Then ContainerType = 37
    If Style = "R" And Size = "240" Then ContainerType = 5
    If Style = "R" And Size = "360" Then ContainerType = 12
    If Style = "Y" And Size = "120" Then ContainerType = 24
    If Style = "Y" And Size = "240" Then ContainerType = 4
    If Style = "Y" And Size = "360" Then ContainerType = 14
    If Style = ("2Y") And Size = "120" Then ContainerType = 9
    If Style = ("2Y") And Size = "240" Then ContainerType = 25
    If Style = ("2Y") And Size = "360" Then ContainerType = 28
    If Style = ("3Y") And Size = "120" Then ContainerType = 9
    If Style = ("3Y") And Size = "240" Then ContainerType = 51
    If Style = ("3Y") And Size = "360" Then ContainerType = 29

End Sub
```

Perhaps there is a better way to do this?

Comment: I'm not seeing any pattern in your `ContainerType` values. Can you explain the mathematics behind this code?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly a "better way to do this" would be to create a table named something like [ContainerType_lookup]:

```
Style  Size  ContainerType
-----  ----  -------------
W      120               9
W      240               2
W      360              34
...
```

and then use either a SQL `JOIN` or the `DLookup()` function to find the appropriate `ContainerType`. That way...

1. You don't necessarily have to modify your code if something changes (like a new ContainerType), and
2. If you ever need to derive the ContainerType anywhere else in the application you don't have to replicate your VBA logic there, too.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion I think you can use Select Case to split it and make it less heavy to read.
You also get some more organisation grouping them by Size or Style depending what you need.

But, i agree that using a table with or without a query will make your life easier here.

```
Select Case Size
    Case "120" 
        If Style = "W" Then ContainerType = 9
        If Style = "R" Then ContainerType = 37
        ...
    Case "240"
        If Style = "W" Then ContainerType = 2
        If Style = "R" Then ContainerType = 5
        ...
    Case "360"
        If Style = "W" Then ContainerType = 34
        If Style = "R" Then ContainerType = 12
        ...
    Case Else
        Exit Sub
End Select
```